# Comparación de campos de modelos en MVC 5

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-5, mvc

Tengo dos modelos:

- Servicio.
- Facturacion.

En el modelo **servicio** tengo un campo llamado **CargoFijoMensual**.

En **Facturacion** varios campos:

- ValorFacturado.
- CargoAdicionalVoz.
- CargoAdicionalDatos.
- CargoAdicional.
- Y otros campos más.

#### Requerimiento

El **Cargo Fijo Mensual** sumado a los **Cargos adicionales** no debe ser mayor al **ValorFacturado**

#### Avances:

Todos los cargos Adicionales ya puedo compararlos desde el modelo Facturacion con ValorFacturado para que su suma no sea mayor.

```
 public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (ValorFacturado < (VozCargoAdicional + DatosCargoAdicional + OtrosCargosAdicional + CargoReposicionArmetales + CargoReposicionUsuario))
        {
            yield return new ValidationResult("Valor facturado es menor", new[] { "El valor es mayor que factura" });
        }
    }
```

Esta validación es única del servidor.

En el controlador muestro el error sencillamente.

```
{                
    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "El valor de cargos adicionales debe ser menos que el valor facturado");
}
```

#### Problema:

Debo agregar a la suma de los cargos adicionales el **CargoFijoMensual** el problema es que lo tengo en mi modelo **Servicio**

> ¿Cómo puedo hacer la validación y llamarlo al mi Modelo **Facturacion**?

Cualquier ayuda estaría más que agradecido, espero sea claro en mis puntos a tratar. gracias de antemano.

Comment: Bienvenido a SO Español. ¿Qué campos relacionan los modelos?

Comment: Hola @PabloClaus  ` NumeroLinea` relaciona los campos

Comment: Ok. Y a nivel objetos，como estan modelados? Capaz puedas poner el código.

Comment: `public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
        {  if (ValorFacturado < (VozCargoAdicional + DatosCargoAdicional + OtrosCargosAdicional + CargoReposicionArmetales + CargoReposicionUsuario))
            {
                yield return new ValidationResult("Valor facturado es menor", new[] { "El valor es mayor que factura" });
            } ` esto es una validación desde el modelo, solo al servidor donde valido que los cargos adicionales no sean mayores al `ValorFacturado` @PabloClaus  debería mandar el `CargoFijoMensual` de la clase servicio

Comment: Perdon por no aclarar. Agrega el codigo a la pregunta. Puede ser?

Comment: `{
  ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "El valor de cargos adicionales debe ser menos que el valor facturado");
  }` @PabloClaus creo que ahí deberias entender y ayudar a mi problema, gacias por la espera.

Comment: Lo que yo te decía era el código de las clases. Cómo están armadas. O sea..el Modelo.

Comment: Hola. A mi modo de ver tu modelo Servicio debería de estar dentro de tu modelo de Facturación. Por lógica una facturación incluye 0..N servicio. Si nos muestras como ya te han indicado cómo has creado tus modelos podemos ayudarte mejor. Saludos

Comment: Saludos bro, ¿Lograste solucionarlo?